# Best design to convert a data object to a DataTable

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I need to convert different data objects implementing the same interface (e.g. IFoo) to a flat DataTable. My current implementation is to create a set of functions that take `IFoo` as input argument, cast IFoo to its class and then return a DataTable.

E.g. for class `Apple`  I have the following function:

```
public DataTable AppleToDataTable (IFoo obj)
{
    Apple apl = obj as Apple;
    // some conversion logic here.
}
```

For class `Orange`, I have something similar :

```
public DataTable OrangeToDataTable (IFoo obj)
{
    Orange org = obj as Orange;
    // some conversion logic here.
}
```

I use a `delegate` to point to this set of the functions. In my config XML file, I have a list of key value pairs that associates my data object with the converter functions (the data objects and converter functions are not 1-to-1 mapping, i.e. for the same data object, I may want to convert it into different DataTables. Each DataTable only contains portion of the data).

When I receive a `IFoo`, it contains a unique id which tells me which data object it is and then I use the mapping in the config file to send the data object to the correct function and get the DataTable.

So my question is: Is there a better design to do this task? Any input is highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: If there's no difference in logic between converting Apple and Orange to DataTable, how about a base class called Fruit that implements IFoo ? Some code on how the class properties and DataTable looks would help

Comment: I find your question hard to understand. Show us a piece of your XML. Show us a piece of your converter functions your delegate is pointing to. In your examples there is no delegate to be found. So please show us more.

Comment: Why not define the interface `IDataTable`, implement it directly in each data object, and derive each data object from it? Or define an explicit or implicit cast from each data object to DataTable? Exactly what you need is unclear from the question as currently written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you has no problem here. I don't think there is any downside with your design, except that you separated the conversion mapping here.

Another way is to use strategic pattern (overloading). For example:

```
public class Converter
{
    public DataTable Convert(Apple obj)
    {

    }
    public DataTable Convert(Orange obj)
    {

    }
    public DataTable Convert(Mango obj)
    {

    }
    public DataTable Convert(Avocado obj)
    {

    }
}
```

IMHO this is cleaner way to do the conversion.